# Transparent framebuffer in GLFW and GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I use the following code to create a window with transparent framebuffer. The following window creation code works fine with Intel graphics card, but when I use a PC with Nvidia graphics card, the transparent framebuffer effect is gone.
Can someone explain and show me how to fix it. Thank you.

```cpp
    // Initialize GLFW Windowing System & OpenGL
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);    // Create windows transparent framebuffer

    m_glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(400, 300, "GLFW Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!m_glfwWindow) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }
```

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);    // Create windows transparent
```

Comment: Read the documentation: *"[`GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html) specifies whether the window framebuffer will be transparent. **If enabled and supported by the system**, the window framebuffer alpha channel will be used to combine the framebuffer with the background."* - So this feature does not work with every system.

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76
In my PC, there are 2 video cards. The default card is Intel and I have another Nvidia video card installed.
When running the program in both cases using Intel and Nvidia cards, I check to see if GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER is supported, and the result is always TRUE.

(I specified the graphics card using Windows' "Graphics Settings")

Comment: Maybe posting screenshots of your results on Intel and NVidia could help to diagnose the problem.